# Iterate through all columns of a jquery datatable and get data from a row which has a specific class

Tags: jquery, dom, datatables

I am trying to get data from a jquery datatable from a row which are having a specific class.

My table looks like below: The datatable also has pagination.

```
ID  |  DocumentID |  FileName |          |
------------------------------------------
1   |          201| abc.cc    | check box|
```

I have added a class to some rows by using the below code:

```
$('body').on('change', 'input.checked-box', function () {

    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {

        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selectedRow');
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('selectedRow');
    }

    if (table.rows('.selectedRow').data().length > 0) {

        $('#downloadDoc').removeClass('inactive');
        $('#downloadDoc').addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $('#downloadDoc').removeClass('active');
        $('#downloadDoc').addClass('inactive');
    }
});
```

In the above code: `input.checked-box` is a checkbox `<input type='checkbox' class='checked-box' id='check0'>`, the checkbox are added to each row with a specific ID. When a checkbox is clicked the corresponding row gets the `class='selectedRow'`. So, the above code is adding a class to each row when the corresponding checkbox is checked. So far working good.

Now, how I can get data of "DocumentID" column (as shown in the above table) for rows which has the `class='selectedRow'` when I click a button (say for `<button id='downloadDoc' class='active'>`)

My HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <button id='downloadDoc' class='inactive'>

  <table id="attachmentList" class="display">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th>Attachment Detail Id</th>
           <th>File Name</th>
           <th></th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the position of that button in your markup??

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy with the table with in the same `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the table rows and select these with the specific class.

Then, get the second cell's text and store it in an array (`arr`)

You can use `eq()` function to target the second cell of each row.

**NOTE:** If you don't know from the begging, the index of `Attachment Detail Id` column, you can do this:

Add an id to the specific column:

```
<tr>
   <th></th>
   <th id="att_id">Attachment Detail Id</th>
   <th>File Name</th>
   <th></th>
</tr>
```

Find the specific column's index, store it in avariable ( `i` ) and pass it to the `eq()` function:

```
var arr = [];
$('#attachmentList').find('tr').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var i = $('#attachmentList').find('#att_id').index();
    var class = that.attr('class');
    if (class == 'selectedRow') {
        arr.push(that.find('td').eq(i).text());
    }
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: but I still not able to get data from next page